# How to find a node id after rotation with scene coordinates?

Tags: javafx, javafx-11

I've made a circle with 50 arcs of 18 degrees , every arc object has its own id in fxml .  I've made a Mouse event to rotate the circle but i need to know which arc is in a certain scene coordinates after the  rotation

[image: spining wheel]

the wheel  is wrapped in a group and the big blue arc in the right rotate the group by mouse event

```
package verbs_wheel.controllers;

import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;

public final class WheelPointRotation {

private Group group;
private double startY;



private Arc wheelHandler;
private boolean isMouseExited = false;


public WheelPointRotation(Group group, Arc wheelHandler) {
    this.wheelHandler = wheelHandler;
    this.group = group;

    this.setOnRotation();
}

private void setOnRotation() {
    wheelHandler.setOnMouseEntered(entered -> {
        isMouseExited = false;
    });

    wheelHandler.setOnMousePressed(pressedEvent -> {
        startY = pressedEvent.getSceneY();
    });
    wheelHandler.setOnMouseDragged(draggedEvent -> {
        wheelHandler.setOnMouseExited(es -> {

            isMouseExited = true;

        });
        if (draggedEvent.getTarget() == wheelHandler) {

            if (isMouseExited) {
                return;
            }
            double dY = (draggedEvent.getSceneY() - startY) / 600;


            group.setRotate(
                    group.getRotate() + dY);
        }


    });


  }
 }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the spinner? How does it rotate? Are there a set number of positions? Please clarify.

Comment: [mcve] please .. don't quite see what's the problem, doesn't the mouse event carry all info you need?

Comment: Any time you are asking something like "How do I get information from my UI?" you are almost always structuring your application and thinking about this in the wrong way. The UI should not be the repository for any data. Instead, move the *data* to a separate class (the "model"); here that's something like the list of words and the amount (number of words) by which the view is offset (rotated). Then arrange for (1) your UI to automatically update when the data change, and (2) your event handlers to update the *data*. Now your question becomes moot; you only need to check the data.

Comment: You set the rotation and the text nodes are probably also positioned using rotation. That should make identifying the text just a matter of finding element where the sum of the angles of the group rotation and the rotation inside the group is closest to a multiple of 360 deg.

Comment: A degree based method is a very good idea . thanks , fabian